# S.L. Weiss - Ciacona Suit 10. How to play this note on guitar?

Tags: guitar, classical-guitar

[image]

(From S.L. Weiss - Ciacona Suit 10, arranged for guitar)

As shown in the red circle.

I found it very hard to place my fingers on guitar to play this. Especially the D4 note.

transcribed to tablature, would be like this: almost impossible for me to play...

```
--4--
--5--
--7--
-----
--2--
-----
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The 6 in a circle says that the B will be played on the 7th fret, bottom string. Just as the C prior is on the 8th fret. Leaving the other three notes as you show. Still not an easy fretting position, but just about doable. It's an E dominant 7th chord inversion, and since it's a transcription, the transcriber has attempted to get it played verbatim to the original. Which often is near impossible on guitar.

Comment: Since the bass note is the fifth, and only lasts a quarter note, it might be forgivable to leave it off if your reach is not up to the task

Comment: @AlexY - trouble is, there is a pattern of bass crotchets before, and probably after.

Comment: from the markup, it appears to me that this would be played `7 x x 7 9 0`, or (from low string to high string) `B x x D G# E`. The marking for 6th position started with the previous chord, and that previous chord had the 'high E' being played with an open string (the 1st string, obviously) and the 'A' being fretted (10 fret, 2nd string presumably) with the 4th finger. So, it seems to me that since we are still in 6th position, and we see markings (from high to low) `4 0 2`, that the 'high E' would still be played open.

So, my vote is for `7 x x 7 9 0` (`B x x D G# E`)

Comment: @DougRisk - it's a way round it, but playing it like that, with an open string? I tried it, and to be very careful how my r.h. fingers worked to even out the tone. It's more a case of someone who hasn't considered the constraints of guitar playin that transcribed it, I feel.